# Stopping a browser programatically by reading a hardware key press in android

Tags: android, keypress, android-browser, infrared

I am developing an application for android tv box with an IR remote . In my application I have successfully launched a web browser from my code ,  and I want to close this browser when the user press a button on the IR remote. I have tried to catch the key event by listening for the dispatch key event in my code , but key event is not getting caught . Could Someone please help me out in catching key press event in my application . Thank you

```
@Override  
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       if(event.getKeyCode()==170) {
       // some code  
        }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putBoolean("new_window", true); 
    i.putExtras(b);
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start a new Activity (i.e. Firefox) then this is the Activity on top and the one that get focus and thus the key events.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to get key events when the user is using firefox? thanks..

Comment: @user2949215 You can't.  That's part of the security model of Android-  key events cannot be redirected or programatically sent to other apps/from other apps.  Instead what you can do is launch your own activity with a WebView in it, rather than using the browser.